# Where to copy woocommerce files to in my custom theme to avoid editing the core plugin?

Tags: php, plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I want to change the loop-start.php so I have copies the entire woocommerce plugin into my theme folder. Then started editing templates/loop/loop-start.php but it does not reflect in my front end. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To override WooCommerce (WC) templates, put your modified templates in
`custom_theme/woocommerce/template-category/template-name.php`

Example: To override the admin order notification, copy:

```
wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/emails/admin-new-order.php
```

to

```
wp-content/themes/yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/admin-new-order.php
```

[WC Documentation Reference](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)